# setting state in handle scroll is showing previous state - react hooks, throttle and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, throttling

I am currently trying to get nav items within my navbar to switch classes when the user scrolls to certain parts of the page. My code is using redux, so that when the user scrolls to x part of the page, I dispatch an action to redux which then changes the classes for the navbar. But my code is making far too many calls to redux as the user scrolls which is slowing down how quickly the user can see changes in the navbar. I have tried using throttle to limit the amount of calls I make to set the Redux state. But this is only working a little bit (there are still too many calls being made). Here is my code for more context:

```
// on scroll change active classes in navbar
useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = (event) => {
    const throttleFunc = throttle(9999999, false, () => {
      // fill info
      if (
        props.readCarefullySect.current.getBoundingClientRect().top > 150 &&
        props.stageData.navTwo !== "active" &&
        !stage.fillInfo
      ) {
        setStage({
          fillInfo: true,
          readCarefully: false,
          signature: false,
        });
        props.activeFillInfo();
      }
      // signature
      else if (
        props.readCarefullySect.current.getBoundingClientRect().top < -3555 &&
        props.stageData.navFour !== "active" &&
        !stage.signature
      ) {
        setStage({
          fillInfo: false,
          readCarefully: false,
          signature: true,
        });
        props.activeSignature();
      }
      // read carefully
      else if (
        props.readCarefullySect.current.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 150 &&
        props.readCarefullySect.current.getBoundingClientRect().top >= -3555 &&
        props.stageData.navThree !== "active" &&
        !stage.readCarefully
      ) {
        setStage({
          fillInfo: false,
          readCarefully: true,
          signature: false,
        });
        console.log("stage in read carefully", stage);
        props.activeReadCarefully();
      }
    });

    throttleFunc();
  };

  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
}, [props, stage]);
```

Because throttle doesn't seem to work as I thought it would, I have tried adding into each conditional an object called 'stage' which should change based on where the user scrolls to. The idea is that if the stage has already been set to equal the section where the user is, then the action should not be dispatched to redux

When I console.log(stage) within each if statement, the if statement is being hit in the correct place, but the stage is stating true/false of the previous position the user was on. For example, my application's stages are (from top to bottom) fill info, read carefully, signature and when the user scrolls from fill info to read carefully, stage currently equals:

```
{ fillInfo: true, readCarefully: false, signature: false }
```

But should equal

```
{ fillInfo: false, readCarefully: true, signature: false }
```

Likewise, if the user were to scroll up again, stage equals

```
{ fillInfo: false, readCarefully: true, signature: false }
```

But should equal

```
{ fillInfo: true, readCarefully: false, signature: false }
```

There must be something I'm doing/not doing that is causing the issue. I'm fairly new to React so any insight is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess your throttle function is a debounce, below is an example of how to do it and you also need to remove the event listener when your effect runs again:

```js
//call function if inactive for time in milliseconds
const debounce = (fn, time = 1000) => {
  let timeOut;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), time);
  };
};
const App = () => {
  const [scrollPos, setScrollPos] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = debounce(() =>
      setScrollPos(Math.floor(window.scrollY))
    );

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    //clean up, scroll listener
    return () => window.removeEventListener(handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {new Array(100).fill('').map((_, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
          scroll position: {scrollPos}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've actually used the throttle from throttle-debounce. It looks like your code doesn't include any if statements so I'm a bit confused as to how it works in relation to setting the classes in the nav items. Bit of a newb so could you explain a little bit what the code is doing?

Comment: @hillybob991 The important things are: a working debounce and remove the event listener in the cleanup function. I can't make a working example from your code because there are many values that are not defined anywhere (maybe a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-elgamal-e2y6x?file=/index.js) can help).

Comment: thanks very much for this. I'll create something later in sandbox and send it across. For some reason it's working much better now (I tweaked the code a bit) but it still dispatches a lot of actions to redux which I imagine might have performance issues further down the line